# QGIS legend different colors

Tags: qgis, legend, color

I want to edit my legend in QGIS 3.28.6 manually (see picture).
Is it possible to output the individual legend elements in different colors?

[image]

For example OK Sand should be green and Grundwasser should be yellow.

Comment: I presume you want to edit the symbology of the points in the map as well as the legend.  It looks like you have a single layer for 6 attributes, and if so you could use the categorized option in symbology to set the colors.  The default ramp likely wouldn't match what you want for color but you can manually change the individual colors.  You could also use rule based symbology but that likely wouldn't be as easy.